# Debit Card Fraud Question

Tags: fraud

Somebody tried to make a purchase with my debit card at a Walgreens in another part the state of I live on.I was notified of the purchase attempt via my bank's fraud detection system. However, I have my debit card with me. How could that be possible? I want to know so I can protect myself from this in the future.

Comment: We are not a personal fraud or banking site.

Answer (score 1):

You might have used a card where someone had a card skimmer installed and they have created a clone of your card.

1. Don't use your card in any device that looks like it has been altered. This Forbes [article](https://www.forbes.com/advisor/credit-cards/how-to-spot-a-credit-card-skimmer/) describes some of the things to look out for, but they constantly improve their attack methods, so there is no 100% certain way to avoid it.
2. Cover the pin pad with your other hand to prevent your pin being re-corded via a hidden camera.
3. Use the chip by inserting the card, rather than swiping and using magnetic strip.

See also this Q & A [Clone debit or credit card](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/107993/clone-debit-or-credit-card?rq=1)